# Bootstrap переместить ссылку снизу

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Здравствуйте! Имеется вот такой контент:

[image: Фото 1]

Как мне при просмотре сайта с мобильными устройствами сместить текст так, чтобы получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот кусок кода:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center language_div">
    <span id="lang_text">Язык:</span>
    <a href="#" class="lang_link">Русский</as>
</div>
```

Дело в том, что если уменьшить экран браузера, то этот div сжимается и нужно как-то переместить ссылку в низу. Но как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно прям всё делать на `bootstrap`

Можно просто добавить правило:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #lang_text {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

```
<span class="col-md-6" id="lang_text">Язык:</span>
<a class="col-md-6" href="#" class="lang_link">Русский</as>
```

ни или `col-md-4` `col-md-8` там просто уже целиться надо.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center language_div">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6>
    <span id="lang_text">Язык:</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6>
    <a href="#" class="lang_link">Русский</a>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.